# Comment résoudre les définitions circulaires de « approvisonner », « équiper », « fournir », « munir », « pourvoir » et « procurer » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Bien que j'aie consulté les dictionnaires, je m'enquiers des différences entre ces synonymes. J'illustre par exemple quelques sources d'enchevêtrement trouvées dans le Larousse :

- [*approvisionner*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/approvisionner/4785?q=approvisionner#4758)  désigne *fournir* et *munir*.
- [*fournir*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/fournir/34862?q=fournir#34826) traite de *approvisionner* et *procurer*.
- [*procurer*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/procurer/64105?q=procurer#63386) se rapporte à *fournir* et *pourvoir*.
- [*équiper*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/%C3%A9quiper/30695?q=equiper#30610) fait allusion à *munir* et *pourvoir*.
- [*munir*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/munir/53276?q=munir#52926) renvoie à *pourvoir*.
- [*pourvoir*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/pourvoir/63152?q=pourvoir#62443) se reporte à *équiper*.

Je conviens qu'il est propice et utile d'apprendre comment résoudre les définitions circulaires en général. Néanmoins, je m’intéresse aux finesses et subtilités de ces six verbes en particulier.

Comment: La question restait spécifique, le titre actuel n'a pas de sens.

Answer (score 2):

Deux remarques :

1- Il n'existe pas deux synonymes parfaits, il y a toujours une nuance, un usage, qui distinguent l'emploi, même si le sens général est le même et reste compréhensible. On ne dira pas "il est approvisonné des papiers en règle pour conduire", ni "il est fourni de provisions pour une randonnée de plusieurs jours".

Même quant à "florilège" et "anthologie", qui pourtant signifient étymologiquement exactement la même chose ; "florilège des citations de Kant" serait mal admis, de même que "anthologie de la poésie courtoise du XIIème siècle" (à moins qu'il ne s'agisse d'un ouvrage pour érudits, et non amateurs).

2- Tout dictionnaire ne pouvant donner une définition que par des mots, eux-mêmes définis par d'autres, il ne peut que boucler sur lui-même et au fond n'explique rien : que faire d'un dictionnaire d'une langue dont on ne sait pas un mot ?
Il faut des points d'entrée déjà connus par l'expérience initialement non verbale.

Comment: Merci. Vous avez illustré dans une phrase que : approvisionner ≠ fournir. SVP, pourriez-vous les éplucher, ainsi que disséquer et dépecer les autres 4 verbes ?

Comment: Réponse à LePressentiment : je viens de rédiger une réponse plus détaillée. Votre commentaire, tout à fait bienvenu, a failli me passer inaperçu, car le classement des nouveautés est un peu brouillon et je relis rarement ce que l'on a dit de moi. Mais mon adresse e-mail est dans mon profil.

Answer (score 0):

La circularité des synonymes amène une difficulté lors du choix du mot.

Les liens indiqués renvoient à des définitions succinctes.

Lorsqu'il y a une ambiguïté, *[le Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/)* (vous pouvez aussi le télécharger pour obtenir l'historique des mots) peut apporter les premiers éclaircissements.

Des recherches plus approfondies sont possibles avec le *[cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/)*.

Les exemples vous indiqueront l'usage habituel de ces mots qui ne sont pas toujours interchangeables.

Comment: @LePressentiment Ne pratiquant pas le SMS (amoureux de la liberté, je n'ai pas de portable) je ne suis pas certain de comprendre ce qui suit le premier point d'interrogation pour essayer de répondre à votre question.

Comment: Merci. J'ai plussoyé. Le CNTRL, fait-il ressortir les points communs et les divergences des 6 verbes, ou ne munit-il que des défns ?

Comment: J'ai modifié mon commentaire. Je voudrais m'enquérir si le CNTRL peut résoudre ma précision ajoutée ci-dessus et mon OP.

Answer (score 0):

Les six termes proposés ont des sens suffisamment distincts pour être définis autrement, et paresseusement, que l'un par l'autre.

**approvisionner = garnir de provisions**

"La ville ne craignait pas un siège : elle était approvisionnée pour six mois de vivres et de munitions".

**équiper = posséder tout ce qui est nécessaire comme équipement**

"Un randonneur est maintenant parfaitement équipé, outre son habillement, avec une paire de jumelles, et l'un de ces appareils électroniques qui servent à la fois de carte, de boussole, de GPS, de podomètre, et de téléphone"

**fournir = faire avoir**

"L'abri avait été fourni de ce qui était minimal pour y passer la nuit".

**munir = posséder tout ce qui est nécessaire de concret ou d'abstrait**

"Lors d'un contrôle, il était heureusement muni de tous les papiers de la voiture".

"Il est décédé, muni des sacrement de l'Eglise".

**pourvoir = suppléer à ce qui manque**

"Il s'est pourvu de conserves pour sa randonnée".

"Le poste vacant a été pourvu par un recrutement externe".

**procurer = faire en sorte que l'on ait quelque chose, avec une certaine idée d'effort(s)**

"Une médication lui a enfin procuré le sommeil".

"En faisant intervenir ses relations, il a pu se procurer un bon emploi".

Comment: Pourquoi mélanger passif et actif ? La seconde définition c'est une définition de *être équipé*, pas de *équiper*. *Faire avoir* ce n'est pas compréhensible. Tu donnes à *munir* la même définition que *équiper* ? Pour la dernière il manque une distinction claire entre *procurer* et *se procurer*.

Comment: Corrections possibles : *fournir* : donner le nécessaire ("Pourvoir de ce qui est nécessaire" - 1ère définition du petit Robert) ; *équiper* (un navire) à la même 1ère définition que *fournir*, c’est à l'origine un terme de marins qui concerne tout ce qui est nécessaire à l'*équipage* d'un bateau.